# How to change transition of .sheet modifier?

Tags: swift, uikit, swiftui

I have a Button that shows a View using the sheet modifier.
The view comes from below. I would like to change the transition, and drop the view from above.

I tried to use

```
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
```

but only the View inside the SheetHostingController is rotated.

This is my code

```
Button(action: { self.showingModal.toggle() }) {
                 Text("Modal")
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showingModal) {
                ContentView(showingHome: self.$showingModal)
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method to make a view transition from top is

```
  .transition(.move(edge: .top))
```

You must add an animation modifier to control this transition

You can combine this transition with other transitions using

```
   .combined(with:)
```

While using modals, I don't think you can add transitions to it.

Comment: This does not work. Where do you suggest adding this? .sheet and .fullscreenCover animations cannot be changed as far as I know